# User expectation for a purchased feature

Tags: usability, usability-testing, e-commerce, users

What does the user expect to see when they upgrade a feature that they future dated?
example: I purchased an add on to an app but set it to start 1 week for now, what should i expect when i look at the dashboard?

[feature I have]   MANAGE
short feature description

Do I display anything here or is the email sent when they upgraded enough?
or would a note on top of the page be enough?

Comment: What type of application is it? Who are the users? How often do these addons get turned on?

Answer (score 1):

### Treat this as a Notification

- Since Dashboard page real estate is very important, I'd suggest you use it as a Notification / Message.
- Place an icon in the global navigation which represents the notification / alert.
- Based on your requirements and if your app supports any other notifications, you can use Bell icon with the number (to show how many notifications are yet to read).
- If your app doesn't have any other notifications, then you can use a plug-in icon to represent the add-ons related information.
- On hover over or click, display the popup with information related to plug-in
- For the purchase process, you may want to send an email. But, I do not recommend just sending an email to the user and not providing any information in the app.

**Note:**

I'm not sure about your requirements, maybe you can disregard some of the points which doesn't make any sense to you.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

By doing something like this.

On the day this feature is available, also show a notification that "One of your widgets / features has been enabled, enjoy your improved experience."

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fIxKID.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>